# Problem while trying to spy on moment.js function

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, momentjs

I've been trying for a project to implement tests with jasmine on some Angular code.

Here is how I tried to make it work

```
beforeEach(() => {
        input = [
            "2020-09-30T21:00:00Z",
            "2020-09-30T21:00:20.2Z",
            "2020-09-30T21:00:00.0002Z",
            "2020-09-30T21:00:00.200002Z"
        ];

    });
    it('sould output a valid date format corresponding to entry date', () => {
        spyOn(moment().tz, 'format').and.callThrough()

        var output = [
            "23:00:00",
            "23:00:20.200",
            "23:00:00.000.2",
            "23:00:00.200.002"
        ];
        expect(myService.myFunction(input[0], "Europe/Paris")).toEqual(output[0]);
        expect(moment.format).toHaveBeenCalledWith('HH:mm:ss');
    });
```

And here is the function

```
let result = moment(date).tz(timezone).format('HH:mm:ss');

    if (date.includes(".")) {
        result += moment(date).tz(timezone).format('.SSS');

        const fracSec = date.split(".")[1].slice(0, -1); //remove Z and get fractionnal seconds
        if (fracSec.length > 3) {
            result += `.${fracSec.slice(-(fracSec.length - 3))}`;
        }
    }
    return result;
```

I've tried multiple solutions, changing spyOn() function call as well as the expect(), but I never made it work. The test fail saying that the function cannot be found.

> ```
>     Error: <spyOn> : format() method does not exist
>     Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
> ```

I've managed to make the spy work with this :

```
spyOn(moment, 'tz').and.returnValue({
            format: jasmine.createSpy()
        });


expect(moment.tz().format).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but then I get an error saying that the function was never called

> Error: Expected spy unknown to have been called.

If you have propositions on how I could get this spy to work, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `moment.tz()` call always returns new value. So the format method will never be the same.

You came close to solving the issue in the last attempt. But in order to be able to check the spy, you need to save it.

```
const formatSpy = jasmine.createSpy();

spyOn(moment, 'tz').and.returnValue({
            format: formatSpy 
        });
// Call your function here.
myService.myFunction();

expect(formatSpy ).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Because this is the unit test, you do not need to be able to call-throught. You can just test that the spy has been called with correct values - because you can be sure that the actual method implementation is correct. You can return bogus info if your code depends on it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand your point, unfortunately, it seems like its not the only problem, I still have the error. `Error: Expected spy unknown to have been called.`

Comment: Also it seems like jasmine can't see the **.tz()** call  :

`const tzSpy = spyOn(moment, 'tz').and.returnValue({ format: formatSpy});`<br/>


`expect(tzSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();`

-> **Error: Expected spy tz to have been called.**

Comment: Well in that case I don't think I can be of help. Moment is old and deprecated. If you're just starting the project, you'd better use a different library.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** As precised by kvetis, one of the problem is that a new format() function exist for each tz() called. I realised that I call moment(date) in my service, wich will probably have a new tz() function for each moment(date) call. I tested this by replacing this line in my service:

```
let result = moment(date).tz(timezone).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

By

```
let result = moment.tz(timezone).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

And sure inoff the test passed, now I need to find a way to get my moment(date) while calling .tz() from the moment **class**. Or a way to handle the new tz() for each new moment() **function** call